# How to bind in PDO a string with %

Tags: php, sql, binding, pdo

I have the following query, (which don't work).
How do I bid strings inside an existing string with % (I believe the % is not the problem, but really not sure).

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM T WHERE f LIKE '%:bindParamString%'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include `%` symbols into your value:

```
 $param = '%'.$param.'%';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM T WHERE f LIKE ?";
```

Or use SQL to concatenate string in database:

```
 ## if you have mysql
 $query = "SELECT * FROM T WHERE f LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

It also a good idea to use `LIKE` instead of `=` then you're searching by patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$db = new PDO(...);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM T WHERE f=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$val = "%{$val}%";
$stmt->bindParam(1, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

For more info, I suggest to read the related [doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)!